# Order alphabetically and group by first letter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, loops, select, haml

I currently have the following code:

```
- @alpha = Glossary.find(:all, :order =>"title ASC").group_by{|u| u.title[0]}
- @glossary = Glossary.find(:all, :order =>"title ASC")

- @alpha.each do|a|

  %h1= a[0]

  - @glossary.each do |g|
    %p display stuff
```

This displays all of the glossary terms under each letter rather than only the ones that begin with the letter.. I've tried a few things but I'm not sure how to select the right thing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to do everything with your `@alpha` instance variable, since you're using `group_by`:

```
- @alpha = Glossary.find(:all, :order =>"title ASC").group_by{|u| u.title[0]}

- @alpha.each do |alpha, glossary_array|
  %h1= alpha
  - glossary_array.each do |item|
    %p= item
```

Comment: How would someone do this in Liquid? [Here is my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35707352/how-to-group-data-by-first-letter-from-a-csv-file-in-liquid).

Answer (score 4):

You're close.  I think you just want to do

```
- @alpha = Glossary.order("title ASC").group_by{|u| u.title[0]}
- @alpha.each do |letter, items|
  %h1= letter
  - items.each do |item|
    %p= item
```